# Django: Integer field that is the count of ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a model with a field

```
countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=True)
```

I want a new field

```
count = models.IntegerField()
```

that is the count of the countries that also updates when countries are added and removed. I know there is a `.count()` method, but I'm not sure how to set my count field equal to that.

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: I tried setting count = self.countries.count() , but self was undefined. I realized it probably needed to be an IntegerField(), but I'm not sure how to set a field equal to a function

Comment: Please, edit your question and provide more information about your `views` and `models`.

Comment: @FranndyAbreu that is my User(AbstractUser) model right now, just the one field, and i'm trying to add another. My view is the django rest framework rest auth user details view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=True)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.count = self.countries.count()
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your self-answer will only update when the user itself is saved, not when just the m2m relation itself is updated. What you need is [the m2m-changed signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).

I've switched out `AbstractUser` for `models.Model` to avoid extra work here, but it is tested and working.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed


class Country(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class User(models.Model):
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, related_name="users", blank=True)
    country_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    # ...

def countries_changed(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    # add, remove, and clear all have pre_ and post_ 
    # events that trigger this signal; we only want to 
    # run this -after- one of those events has completed, 
    # to get the final count.
    if action.startswith("post_"):
        instance.country_count = instance.countries.count()
        instance.save()

m2m_changed.connect(countries_changed, sender=User.countries.through)
```

Example (run in an interactive `./manage.py shell`):

```
from eh.models import User, Country


user = User()
user.save()

print(user.country_count)
# 0

countries = (Country.objects.create() for i in range(10))

for c in countries:
    user.countries.add(c)
    print(user.country_count)
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8
# 9
# 10

user.countries.remove(user.countries.first())
print(user.country_count)
# 9

user.countries.clear()
print(user.country_count)
# 0
```

Note, however, that this *will not* catch instances where a Country is deleted (you could additionally use the `pre_delete` signal connected to the Country model for that).

Comment: With mine, when I add a country in my rest-auth UserDetail view, it updates. I'm working on having my React front end send post requests at the moment, which is the only way I would ever update the countries, which means the count. If it works that way, should I change it? Also I'm not planning on deleting countries, but I guess that's really more dependent on politics

Comment: If what you have works for your use case, and you're certain that will be the entire scope in which this needs to work, then there's not much reason to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `models` should be something like this:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

In your `views.py` whenever you are creating a new `Country` object, before saving the object you can do:

```
object.country.count += 1
object.save()
```

Comment: My countries are all the countries in the world, so they aren't going to be new ones added. I want the count to increase when another country is added to the ManyToMany field relation with the User. I'm not going to write any views since I'm using the default DRF rest-auth view.